# Order of Elements in Bootstrap "form-inline" Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three elements in a `<div>` with the class `form-inline`. A button and two Input boxes. I however can't get the `<button>` to be the first element in the line like this:

`<button></button><input type="text"><input type="text">`

The button is displayed after the two input elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-inline">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Defaults:</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Select Options</button>
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12" />
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootply:** http://www.bootply.com/hkprFNmeLe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the `col-*` from `input`, because according to [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) it isn't used in the forms

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Defaults:</label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Select Options</button>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works too. But how can I set the widths of the inputs without setting their individual widths ?

Comment: Take a look here at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), this is how you should have a `form-inline`

Answer (score 1):

you've forgot the grid `col-x-y` classes on your `button`...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">Select Options</button>
```

see http://www.bootply.com/EKzV0GZpKX#

Comment: I see there are so many different ways to do this based on all the answers. Which one is the recommended way to do this and keep everything responsive too?

Answer (score 0):

Float the button to the left:

```
.form-inline button{float:left;}

.form-inline input{float:right;}
```